# What's a good place to start reading DC comic books?

Tags: comics, dc, suggested-order

I'm starting to read DC comic books but I don't know where to start.

It's pretty easy with Marvel thanks to Marvel Platinum series but I can't seem to find something like that but for DC.

Is there a definitive **(e.g. non-subjective**) answer to question of which are the most important comics and story-arcs? Something suggested by the publishers or authors or the experts?

Comment: The reason this might be getting downvoted is because there are a *lot* of places to start reading DC, as it's a multi-franchise company. A little more info on where you want to start (since it has 70+ years of history) would help this question out a lot.

Comment: I voted to close. That said, I'm minded to reopen if we can find a definitive source

Comment: I posted an answer assuming that the OP is talking about the Justice League. That's generally the main focus of DC Comics for most people, so I thought it was a safe place to start. The question could use some clarification, though.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote. I'll still be downvoting anyone whose answer is basically "*I personally think that these are the best...*"

Comment: If you have a local library, check that out. In Delaware, our library system has tons of graphic novels, both old and new. That's how I got started, and it's the easiest and cheapest way to find what you like.

Comment: Didn't DC do a bunch of Omnibus (What is the plural of that? Omnibusi? Omnibuses?) of everything from Plastic Man to Teen Titans and every other "major" title they've done?

Comment: In spite of being an interesting question, I think it is "too broad", since it will have too many valid answers. Also, possible duplicate of [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4198/32339)?

Comment: @Richard - I edited my answer to remove the "Personally, I would recommend" part. If you want to get started with the Justice League or other core DC characters, the rest of my answer is valid without that disclaimer.

Comment: So do you mean: Where to start to catch up with DC today?  Because if so you could start with the 1st of any New 52 collection.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider getting hold of a copy of the "[DC Entertainment Essential Graphic Novels and Chronology](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Entertainment-Essential-Graphic-Novels-Chronology-ebook/dp/B00K7EIY70)". This book details the comics that DC thinks are most important as well as listing "essential" back-catalogue items for DC's main properties; Superman, Batman, Green Lantern, The Flash, Justice League, Wonder Woman,  Green Arrow, Justice Society of America, Legion of Superheroes and the Teen Titans.

Most of their 'essential' stories have been marketed under the "[Greatest Stories Ever Told](http://www.goodreads.com/series/51371-the-greatest-stories-ever-told)" banner. You certainly couldn't go wrong reading those.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch up with the current continuity, look for books set in the New 52 universe. Most people think of the Justice League when they think DC Comics, so here are some suggestions that will catch you up on the New 52 version of the Justice League:

- [Justice League: Vol. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401237886)
- [Justice League: Vol. 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401237657)
- [Justice League: Vol. 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401246982)

If you're more interested in the previous continuity that occurred for most of the 2000's, here are some recommendations for that version of the Justice League:

- [JLA: Volume 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401233147)
- [JLA: Volume 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401235182)
- [JLA: Volume 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401238327)

Trade paperbacks are collected editions of popular story arcs, so it's a great way to catch up on major plotlines. The downside is that they don't always include every issue and therefore might have some missing gaps.

If you want character-specific titles or something else entirely, I would recommend going to Amazon (or your preferred online retailer) and search for the name of the character you want and the acronym TPB (ex - "Batman TPB"). On Amazon, you can also include the search term "New 52" to look for items specific to that continuity. You generally want to look for titles like "Batman: Volume 1" when looking for the core stories.

Alternatively, if you just want to catch up on the whole New 52 thing, I also recommend the following animated films:

- [Justice League: The FlashPoint Paradox](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CENWUYK)
- [Justice League: War](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GD9GNUS)

The first is the adaptation of "FlashPoint", which is the event that changed everything to the New 52 continuity. The second is the adaptation of how the Justice League first formed in the new continuity.

Comment: This still seems really subjective

Comment: Any suggestions for cleanup? Given how broad the question is (and whether or not it gets closed) I may just remove the answer as well.

Comment: I don't honestly think you can clean this one up. If your answer is essentially "***I*** think that...", then you're referencing yourself as an expert.

Comment: Well, 30+ years of reading DC comics makes me at a minimum fairly knowledgeable. But at any rate, I'd like to keep the site neat & tidy so will gladly remove the answer if you think it's warranted.

Comment: I've downvoted (for the reasons discussed above) but it's not *not* an answer. Deleting it is your decision and certainly not mine to make.

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure - I'm still fairly new here.