# What's the perfect place to start reading DC comics for a newbie?

Tags: comics, dc, suggested-order

I am a newbie in comics. Although I'm well aware with all the DC characters and have seen all the movies, I think it's time for me start diving into comics as they're the real deal and I've always wanted to read comics. I like the Batman (who doesn't!) and the Flash (because he's cool). Superman is pretty cool as well. So where do I start reading their comics, if I want to get to know about their history, how they originated and their present *without* missing anything. I don't want to miss stories where they fought together and stuff as well. A friend suggested DC's New 52 saying "it was a complete reboot of the entire DC universe.". So would you guys recommend it as well? Also, I prefer comics with good artwork rather than some lame looking Batman.

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts! Thanks.

Comment: As a complete noob in DC comics, I myself have found the new 52 a fantastic way to start reading comics. I have tried picking up some Marvel comics and even with the Marvel Now event, it's very hard. Your friend is definitely right, the new 52 is a perfect start.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández That sounds like the start of an answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good place to start reading DC comic books?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68973/whats-a-good-place-to-start-reading-dc-comic-books)

Comment: [This might be a duplicate](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68973/32339) or [here, for The Flash](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4198/32339)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that there are two big dampers on reading comic books **cost** and **finding complete stories**.

When I started reading DC comics I went to a used bookstore and looked for consecutive issues of individual titles.  I wound up with a 5 issues of Teen Titans from 1995 and the first 3 issues of Young Justice for around $10. That said I was able to read large plot arcs without getting too lost.

I often still use this tactic to find new (always used) comics for my collection.  I look for titles from a specific year and fill in runs of an individual title.  Sometime special editions are a great place to go to. For 99 cents I was able to get a single part issue of the Atom which was pretty complete and easy to follow (And like 4 times as big as a normal comic book).

Also graphic novels and/or volumes containing multiple issues of a story arch can be a great and budget friendly option as well.

You mentioned liking 3 of the biggies in the DC universe so while you are familiar with the big names, some of the most fun characters are a bit lesser known.  You might want to look around and find out what other titles might interest you.  A good way to find that out is watching cartoons and seeing which "guest" characters make an appearance and finding out via the internet what titles and issues that particular character makes an appearance in.

I'm not much of a fan of the new 52 as so many of the characters I really like got dumped or had their origin story butchered by the reboot, but you might like it and have an easy time acquiring consecutive issues with it though.

Also, wiki pages tend to have good records of issues pertaining to various character arcs, so if you want to find out the origins of a particular character (as it may not be shown in issue #1...probably won't be shown in issue #1) the source materials are usually linked to that bio.

The best advise I can give you is find the titles you truly find interesting and have fun.

Answer (score -1):

The latest issue of Batgirl is a good jumping-on point, and Gotham Academy just started up. You might also want to check out older books like Batman Year One, The Dark Knight Returns, The Killing Joke, etc.

Other than that, just  go into your local comic shop and ask them the question. They'll be able to point you to some books, and you can check out the art to see if it's something you're into.

Comment: I would suggest Justice League 1 (2011). It introduces the characters for the first time and their powers. It doesn't reference PC material. Most of the major crossovers filter through Justice League - read the Trinity crossover, even though it's rubbish because it leads into the excellent Forever Evil. Decide which characters you like and pick up their individual books. I enjoy Superman Wonder Woman and Batman Superman even though I'm not a big fan of Superman due to his lack of charisma. The opening Aquaman issues were good but one Aquaman story is more or less the same as the next.